# Jquery navigating through tabs using Next/Prev buttons does not render map and calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I had this problem of rendering maps or calendar placed on the hidden tabs a while ago and I finally managed to solve it using resize or render functions WHEN directly click on the tabs. It is still working fine.

I have recently added the next and prev buttons to my tabs and the issue is when I navigate through the tabs using those buttons, the maps or calendars does not render for the first time. but renders fine for the second time. that is when you click one more next to pass the tab containing the map and then click the prev button its all fine.

Has anyone experienced same issue or got any idea how to solve this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put all your resize and render functions with the event callback for tabshow

This event is triggered when a tab is shown.

[Code examples from Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-show)

```
Supply a callback function to handle the show event as an init option.
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   show: function(event, ui) { ... 
     // Objects available in the function context:
ui.tab     // anchor element of the selected (clicked) tab
ui.panel   // element, that contains the selected/clicked tab contents
ui.index   // zero-based index of the selected (clicked) tab

    }
});

OR

Bind to the show event by type: tabsshow.
$( ".selector" ).bind( "tabsshow", function(event, ui) {
  ...


});
```

Comment: thats what i have already done and its working properly. As I mentioned it only has got problem when it come to next and prev button usage. when you go to the tab containing the map or calendar using the next button.

Comment: its strange cause when I click pass the tab and return back, it renders!!

Comment: which functions are you using to rerender the calendar and map?

Comment: For Calendar:
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('render'); 
and for map:
addressMap.checkResize();
addressMap.setCenter(center, zoom);

Comment: sorry I was under the impression that you were using jquery ui calendar and google maps. Which plugins are you using?

Comment: I should have mentioned from the beginning : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ for the calendar and CloudMade for the map

Comment: what code are you using to switch tabs? if your using .tabs( "select" , index ) the same functions should still work